# How to extrude on YZ plane only along normals

Tags: modeling

I am trying to make a fire place and I need to extrude a boundary edge loop which I selected and separated from my initial mesh so that I can have some geometry to make into brick slabs, here's an image of what I'm trying to get to

[image: desired]

The problem is that the outlined edge I am using has normals which point along X axis.

[image: normals]

I want them to point outward so I can extrude evenly somehow.

[image: desired normals]

I used to use an addon called the sire outliner for things like this years ago, but now we're in Blender 4 I don't think that works anymore, if there's a more native way to do this I would like to know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable the addon called *Mesh: Edit Mesh Tools*, then select all and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Offset Edges > Extrude*:

[image]

Then in the *Operator Box* you can change the *Width*:

[image]

Comment: as a geonoder the way I would do this is extrude along Y, then extrude faces then delete the excess edges (those that don't share Y coordinate of original geometry)

Comment: yes that was the former way to do it before this addon